# Calling Python process (which executes tycat-terminology image display utility) from Java DOES NOT WORK

Tags: java, python, bash, unix, terminology

I want basically to display images into the console terminal, from a Java main program class. The images should show only in the main terminal console, AND NOT open new image display utility windows (i.e. imagemagick, eog, etc.)

I have tried the following workaround: The following Python code (display_image.py) starts tycat/terminology image display utility that successfully shows an image in the console terminal:

```
import os
os.system("tycat -g 100x100 /home/user/Dekstop/image.png")
```

So when I execute that Python snippet everything fine. But, when I process call it from Java, like this way here:

```
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"python","/home/user/Desktop/display_image.py"});

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    String s1 = null;
    while ((s1 = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
```

The process seems hanged and does not show anything. Note, that I run the java class from terminology, still the same issue.

I would appreciate any hint or help that would either solve this problem, OR help me show any image file from Java class inside the terminal console application.

Thanks

Comment: Does `tycat` mention anything about requiring a live terminal anywhere in the documentation? Does it require input you are not providing? A quick glance at the [`tycat` source code](https://github.com/billiob/terminology/blob/master/src/bin/tycat.c) I see `scanf`, so it *reads from stdin*. Are you providing that input anywhere?

Comment: tycat should be called from inside terminology environment. It can take as input any image file in the format: $ tycat <image_file>

Comment: I use `import subprocess`, then build a command-string like `command = 'tycat -g 20x100 image.png'` and finally call it using `subprocess.Popen(command.split())` or `subprocess.check_output(command.split())`.